# Check in C if a PyObject is Cython function

Tags: cython

I have embedded Python 2.7 in C++ application and used Cython to compile a few modules from pure python into c then into shared objects.

Well, module functions compiled by Cython have totally different type than python pure function.

```
type(func) # <type 'cython_function_or_method'>
```

is there a way to check that type like `PyList_Check` using the Python C-API.
Or does Cython provide a C-api interface to be used like `Python.h` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cython functions are of type `PyCFunction` and not of type `PyFunction` as the usual pure Python-functions (the missing C in name makes a difference!).

Thus you could use `PyCFunction_Check` to check whether the function at hand is possible a Cython-function.

There is a lot of functionality from CPython which can be imported via `from cpython cimport XXXX`.  However not all functionality is wrapped, and also not `PyCFunction_Check`.

But this is not a problem, because it can be easily imported from `Python.h`:

```
%%cython
cdef extern from "Python.h":
    int PyCFunction_Check(object obj)

def is_cython_function(obj):
    return PyCFunction_Check(obj)!=0
```

This is somewhat dirty, because `PyCFunction_Check` is a define and not a function, but it works nevertheless.

And now:

```
def dummy():
    pass

is_cython_function(dummy)   #  False
is_cython_function(is_cython_function) # True
```

However, the name of the function "`is_cython_function`" is somewhat misleading - it will be `True` for every build-in function:

```
is_cython_function(abs)  # True
```

However, normally you are not interested that a function is from cython, but whether is is of type `PyCFunction` or not (and by the way, for me `type(is_cython_function)` says: "`<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>`".